# How to get secret from a secured keyvault when using logic app in Azure api management?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault, azure-api-management

I'm working on securing a logic app using APIM, my logic app contains an action that gets secret from a keyvault, my keyvault uses a private endpoint for connection, i have configured also a private endpoint for the APIM in the same subnet of the kv private endpoint.

The problem is that when i test the api i got **HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway** error.
and the logic app fails with this error :

```
    "message": "The operation failed because the client does not have permission to perform the operation on the key vault. Check your permissions in key vault access policies https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal."
```

and every time i run the logic app from APIM i get this :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NoResponse",
        "message": "The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. Request tracking id ''."
    }
}
```

Please let me know what mistake i have done and what should i do to fix this issue

I have added all the permissions to the api management in the keyvault access policies :

[image]

Flow code

```
{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
        "For_each": {
            "actions": {
                "Compose": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "AadUserId": "@{items('For_each')?['id']}",
                        "UserPrincipalName": "@{items('For_each')?['userPrincipalName']}"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "Compose"
                },
                "Send_Data": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "body": "@{items('For_each')}",
                        "headers": {
                            "Log-Type": "AD_groups"
                        },
                        "host": {
                            "connection": {
                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureloganalyticsdatacollector']['connectionId']"
                            }
                        },
                        "method": "post",
                        "path": "/api/logs"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {
                        "Compose": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "ApiConnection"
                }
            },
            "foreach": "@body('Get_group_members')?['value']",
            "runAfter": {
                "Get_group_members": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Foreach"
        },
        "Get_group_members": {
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuread_1']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/v1.0/groups/@{encodeURIComponent(variables('GroupID'))}/members"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Group_ID_variable": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        },
        "Get_secret": {
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['keyvault_1']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/secrets/@{encodeURIComponent('SPSecret')}/value"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        },
        "Group_ID_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "GroupID",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "**"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Get_secret": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "InitializeVariable"
        },
        "Response": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": "Run succeeded",
                "statusCode": 200
            },
            "kind": "Http",
            "runAfter": {
                "For_each": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Response"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "defaultValue": {},
            "type": "Object"
        }
    },
    "triggers": {
        "manual": {
            "inputs": {
                "schema": {
                    "properties": {},
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "kind": "Http",
            "type": "Request"
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "azuread_1": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/rg-playbook-test-networking/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azuread",
                "connectionName": "azuread",
                "id": "/subscriptions/**/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/canadacentral/managedApis/azuread"
            },
            "azureloganalyticsdatacollector": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/rg-playbook-test-networking/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureloganalyticsdatacollector",
                "connectionName": "azureloganalyticsdatacollector",
                "id": "/subscriptions/**/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/canadacentral/managedApis/azureloganalyticsdatacollector"
            },
            "keyvault_1": {
                "connectionId": "/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/rg-playbook-test-networking/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/keyvault-2",
                "connectionName": "keyvault-2",
                "connectionProperties": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
                    }
                },
                "id": "/subscriptions/**/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/canadacentral/managedApis/keyvault"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How are you making the call to get the secret? I guess my question is, is there any reason why you’re not using a managed identity?

Comment: @Skin i have an action in the logic app that gets secret from keyvault so when i run the logic app from the apim it fails

Comment: Yes but how are you making the call to get the secret? The built in get secret action or a HTTP call? Show your flow.

Comment: @Skin thank you for your interaction, I have updated the question with code off the logic app

Comment: I don’t think you’ve setup the auth properly. It may be the private endpoint but firstly, I’d try to fix the security settings.

Comment: @Skin when i've enabled the public access to the KV i've got a successful run but i want to work with  the private endpoint

Comment: I don't think you can.  Consumption LogicApps don't have VNet integration as an option.  I think you need to configure the security on the KV and go with that.  Otherwise, you need to look at using a Standard LogicApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, as @Skin said, you can achieve this only using standard logic apps. Below are the steps I followed to integrate logic apps with key vault configured with private network.

Firstly, I have integrated logic apps with Vnet.

[image]

Then I have added access policy in my key vault

[image]

and I have added the below two roles in my key vault

[image]

Below is the flow of my logic app

[image]

*Results:*

[image]